# Cannot get an inner div to overlay an outer div

Tags: javascript, css

I have a situation as shown in screen shot below where I would like an inner div to overlay an outer div when outer div has a CSS of `position:relative`. I have tried to do this, which you can see in following online demo: [Demo of my code](http://js.do/sun21170/100502)

[image: Overlay a Div]

- I have two JavaScript methods called *overlay* and *undoOverlay*.
- When I call the *overlay* method, the id of div to overlay and id of div to cover are passed, but it does not result in the yellow div to cover/overlay the outer orange div.
- The *undoOverlay* method returns the overlayed div to it's original state.

**Question**: How can I make the method `overlay` work as expected i.e. it should cause the yellow div to exactly overlay/cover the orange div?

**JavaScript code I have tried for this situation**

```
<button type="button" onclick="overlay('div2','div1');">Overlay Yellow Div on Orange Div</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button type="button" onclick="undoOverlay('div2');">UNDO Overlay</button>
<br><br>
<div id="div1" style="position:relative;background-color:orange;border:2px solid red;height:500px;width:300px;">This is OUTER div
<div id="div2" style="background-color:lightyellow;border:2px solid green;height:400px;width:270px;">This is INNER div</div>
</div>

<script>
//original dimensions of div to show when overlaying
var originalWidth = null;
var originalHeight = null;

//makes first div to exactly cover the second div
function overlay(divIdToShow, divIdToCover) {
   originalWidth = document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.width;
   originalHeight = document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.height;
   document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.width =  document.getElementById(divIdToCover).style.width;
   document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.height =  document.getElementById(divIdToCover).style.height;
}

//returns an overlayed div to it's original state
function undoOverlay(divId) {
   document.getElementById(divId).style.width =  originalWidth;;
   document.getElementById(divId).style.height =  originalHeight;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#div1 {
  position:relative;
  background-color:orange;
  /*border:2px solid red;*/
  outline:2px solid red;
  height:500px;
  width:300px;
}
#div2 {
  background-color:lightyellow;
  /*border:2px solid green;*/
  outline:2px solid green;
  /*height:400px;*/
  /*width:270px;*/
  /*display: none;*/
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.normal {
  height: 400px;
  width: 270px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="toggleOverlay('div2',true);">Overlay Yellow Div on Orange Div</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button type="button" onclick="toggleOverlay('div2',false);">UNDO Overlay</button>
<br><br>
<div id="div1" style="">This is Orange BASE div
<div id="div2" class="normal" style="">This is Yellow OVERLAY div</div>
</div>

<script>
//var originalWidth = document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.width + "px";
//var originalHeight = document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.height + "px";
  
function toggleOverlay(id, show) {
  if (show) {
    //makes first div to exactly cover the second div
    document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute('class'); 
    document.getElementById(id).className = "overlay";
  }
  else {
    //returns an overlayed div to it's original height and width
    document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute('class'); 
    document.getElementById(id).className = "normal";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed in  your snippet that the undo overlay button does not restore the original state of inner div.

Comment: Maybe because you do not have the undoOverlay method in your code snippet. I will try it out.

Comment: My code is more clean.  I didn't need two methods to toggle a div on and off when a boolean parameter would do.

Comment: Ok. The overlayed div results in being hidden when `overlay method` in your snippet gets called for undoing overlay. I would like it to return to it's original state.

Comment: I guess I don't get what you mean by "original state".  In my answer, the original state is either display:block or display:none depending on which way you set the css.  The javascript method toggles this state from one to the other.  So, I consider my answer returning to an original state.

Comment: By original state I meant that it should be like it is in the screen shot I have in my question post.

Comment: I'm still not getting your meaning.  If I were to guess based on your recent comments, you seem to be wanting the inner div to be visible but smaller and inside the outer div.  When the toggle is called, the inner div should completely fill the outer....Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115851/discussion-between-jason-williams-and-sunil).

Comment: Yes, when overlay button is clicked the inner div should cover the outer div, and when undo overlay button is clicked then the divs should return to how they were in screen shot I have given in my question.

Comment: I've made the updates you requested.  Please take another look at the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely do not need JS for this. Just position the inner div with `position: absolute`.

Add this to your inner div:

```
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button" onclick="overlay('div2','div1');">Overlay Yellow Div on Orange Div</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button type="button" onclick="undoOverlay('div2');">UNDO Overlay</button>
<br><br>
<div id="div1" style="position:relative;background-color:orange;border:2px solid red;height:500px;width:300px;">This is OUTER div
<div id="div2" style="background-color:lightyellow;border:2px solid green;min-height:400px;min-width:270px;">This is INNER div</div>
</div>

<script>
//original dimensions of div to show when overlaying
var originalWidth = null;
var originalHeight = null;

function overlay(divIdToShow, divIdToCover) {
   originalWidth = document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.width;
   originalHeight = document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.height;
   document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.position = "absolute";  
   document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.top = '0';
   document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.bottom = '0';
   document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.left = '0';
   document.getElementById(divIdToShow).style.right = '0';
}
function undoOverlay(divId) {
   document.getElementById(divId).style.width =  originalWidth;;
   document.getElementById(divId).style.height =  originalHeight;
}
</script>
```